# Jech Set Theory exercise 12.8

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to solve this:

> If $\alpha > \omega$, then $V_\alpha$ is a model of Infinity (Axiom of Infinity).

I have a few questions. I know by assumption that if $\omega\in\alpha\in V_\alpha$  then $\omega\in V_\alpha$ because $V_\alpha$ is transitive.  So it has an inductive set $\omega$. Is that enough? Do I need to explain anything else? Any hints?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: For transitive models, it’s generally sufficient to just observe that $\omega$ is an element. But to understand why that’s sufficient, you need to be able to explain how we know that “$\omega$ is an inductive set” is true in $V_\alpha$ (not just in $V$).

Comment: Okey. But I think it is obvious. Definition of an inductive set is a simple formula, so is satisfied in $V_\alpha$.

Comment: Whether there is a need to add more or not depends on who is grading your questions. In principle, yes, that is enough. Depending on the exact formulation of the Axiom of Infinity, you might need to prove something more or apply some kind of result about transitive sets, etc. But in principle, arguing that since $\omega\in V_\alpha$, then $V_\alpha$ satisfies the Axiom of Infinity is enough.

Comment: All right, thanks.

Comment: There's a minor mistake in your working. We have $\alpha \subseteq V_\alpha$, but not $\alpha \in V_\alpha$.

Comment: Statement $\alpha\in V_\alpha$ is true because $V_\alpha \cap\ ON=\alpha$.

Comment: That does not imply $\alpha \in V_\alpha$. For example, $V_\omega$ is the set of all hereditarily finite sets, so certainly $\omega \notin V_\omega$.

Comment: But $V_\alpha\cap V=V_\alpha$, does that mean that $V_\alpha\in V_\alpha$?

Comment: Ohhh okey, I see now, that was a huge mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ClementYung You were right, my mistake.